# How to place a window in a specific spot while you have resized it to fit a device

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to be able to resize my windows but have them be placed in a specific spot as well. However I can figure out how to do this. This some example code:

```
import tkinter

window = tkinter.Tk()
window1 = tkinter.Tk()

width = window.winfo_screenwidth()
height = window.winfo_screenheight()

window.geometry("%dx%d" % (width * 2/3, height) + 0 + 0)
window1.geometry("%dx%d" % (width * 1/3, height) + 0 + 0)

window.mainloop()
window1.mainloop()
```

If I do this code then I get this error:

TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str

Comment: It's generally not a good idea to create more than one instance of `Tk` unless you understand why.

Comment: My app I am planning to make will need two instances of Tk though.

Comment: Do you really need two instances of `Tk`, or do you need two windows? The normal way to create windows is that the second window is an instance of `Toplevel`. Are you aware that each instance of `Tk` has its own internal tcl interpreter? That can be useful, but it also comes with some non-intuitive behavior.

Comment: Yeah I do need two instances of TK I believe.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The official documentation says this about the geometry specification:

> *NewGeometry* has the form =widthxheight±x±y, where any of =, widthxheight, or ±x±y may be omitted.

For example, to place your window so that the upper left corner is at 0,0,  you would do something like this:

```
window.geometry("%dx%d+%d+%d" % (width * 2/3, height, 0, 0))
```